# Transparent Button on Blurred Background

Tags: html, css, button

I want to have transparent buttons on the website and if you hover over it it blurs only the background. The Problem is that i have a blurred background. The Button shouldn't be blurred but the rest around it should. Only if you hover it the Background of the button should blur.
inside the border it should be the clean picture and if you hover it it will blur.

[image: Image:]

The buttons are inside the class of the blurred background:

```
div class="blured-background">
        <div class="sign">
          <button class="sign-in">
            sign in
          </button>
          <button class="sign-up">
            sign up
          </button>
        </div> 
      </div>
```

A solution idea is to make an other class for the Buttons and blur the border or something like that but I think there is a easier solution.

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of what you currently have, not just isolated snippets that lack context.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+transparent+background+blurred+button+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: _"The Button shouldn't be blurred"_ - then you need to take it out of your `.blured-background` element to begin with. _"inside the border it should be the clean picture and if you hover it it will blur"_ - since you can't "un-blur" something that has already been blurred, the only option I see here for this, is to assign the _not_ blurred image as background image for the button. But you will have to figure out the `background-position`, so that inside the button, the right _portion_ of the background image gets shown ... might be hard to achieve, if you need this to be in any way responsive.